# UIView frame and bounds wrong

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView subclass that I'm adding some `CALayers` to. I've added this `UIView` to my view via storyboard. For some reason accessing the frame and bounds in the init (and in awakeFromNib) are always (0, 0, 1000, 1000). Why is this?

```
class SliderView: UIView {
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // The bounds are wrong
        trackLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath

    }
}
```

Comment: Try overriding `initWithFrame:`.

Comment: @rmaddy I did that too. My code is actually in a shared init method thats called from both coder and initWithFrame. But since I'm adding it to the storyboard, it's only ever the coder that's called.

Comment: Get the frame in layoutSubviews, after layout constraints have been applied.

Comment: @JamesP Could do. LayoutSubviews does get called multiple times though

Comment: @Tometoyou, Were you able to resolve the issue? Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @JiteshW Yeah putting the code in drawRect worked!

Comment: That's a terrible idea! And drawRect gets called just as much as layoutSubviews anyway.

Comment: @JamesP but at the first call drawRect you have good bounds

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had the same problem in UITableViewCell. 
This workaround should work

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    customInit()
}

var initialized = false
func customInit(){
    if !initialized{
        initialized = true

    // Bounds will be good. Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

In your case it should look like this:

```
class SliderView: UIView {
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // The bounds are wrong
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        customInit()
    }

    var initialized = false
    func customInit() {
        if !initialized {
            initialized = true

            // Bounds will be good.
            trackLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).CGPath
        }
    }
}
```